# how to add http header for authentication to Chromecast request

Tags: sdk, chromecast, google-cast, receiver, google-cast-sdk

While integrating Chromecast into iOS app, I have faced the problem accessing media content that requires authentication. In this particular case, authentication token must be added to the request in the http header, not as token in the url. There does not seem to be a way to do this with Cast SDK directly. So I have played with custom CAF receiver app, hoping that I can pass this data through customdata to receiver app and receiver app then would form the request with proper http header using playerManager.setMessageInterceptor. But again, how to add custom http header to the final request in the CAF receiver app?

Comment: Is there anybody from @google here ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();

const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();

const playbackConfig = new cast.framework.PlaybackConfig();
playbackConfig.manifestRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
    requestInfo.headers = {SomeHeader: "SomeValue", Hello: "World"};
};

playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, requestData => {
        console.log("loaded " + requestData.media.contentId);
        playerManager.setPlaybackConfig(playbackConfig);
        return requestData;
    }
);
```